# Twitter Bootstrap favicon.ico

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a site using the one of the twitter bootstrap templates and my JavaScript console is complaining that it is missing:

```
 favicon.ico

 ie-emulation-modes-warning.js
```

I downloaded all of the Bootstrap files from the Bootstrap website.  What are these files and do I need them?

If so, where can I get them?

Edit:  Thanks guys!  Looked into Favicons and didn't realize that is what they are!  So simple! lol

Comment: Did any of the responses answer you question? If so can you mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, browsers look for favicons in your site's root directory. You can use favicon generators online, which (by standard) create 16x16 pixel png-like objects that are used as your site's icon on a browser tab, etc. Just make one of those and drop it in your root directory.

If that doesn't work, you may want to use your inspector (assuming you're using chrome), right click > inspect element > console (or network), and look there to see where your template is looking for the favicon. Just drop the generated .ico file in that folder.

For the JS file, you may be able to find it online, download it, use the inspector again, and drop it wherever your browser is looking for it. This is good for performance—missing files slow roundtrip requests down.

Answer (score 1):

It's something browsers look for by default. Nothing to do with Bootstrap

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon